# OneNote 2016 Font Changing

Tags: fonts, microsoft-onenote

I received a onenote document from a friend who is using the 2016 version of onenote, just like myself. For some reason, he likes the comic sans font whereas I prefer a more traditional font. Anyway, I have changed the font to my default, which is Times New Roman, but when I press enter to add a new paragraph, the font reverts to comic sans. This is really irritating. Is there a way to make the font I want stick ?

Comment: click  in the ribbon Styles > Normal;  set it  to Heading 1, and kept switching back to the Heading 1 format on return. All I found about your query was this try this first otherwise will find more and in details. But this problem is very common in onenote and is not solved yet. :)

Comment: Is there a way to select all equations in OneNote 2016 so that I can clear formatting and then reformat my equations to the way they were ?

Comment: 1)Move cursor to end of the line which has the font you would like to keep using
Click Styles > Normal
2)Step 2 is tricky because when you select the "Styles" drop-down it will look like "Normal" is already selected. Go ahead and click "Normal" even if it looks like it is already selected.
3)Press the Enter key
4)Type some text.. TRY THIS WILL HELP I GUESS SO

Comment: Selecting normal removes all other formatting such as color. That only makes things worse.

Comment: But it will help you to remove that font I guess. After converting it to NORMAL you can select colour and all other format.

Comment: Go through this discussion as this error is not fixed correctly. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/233833f7-dde8-414d-bdca-604ed8d57667/onenote-2013-font-changes-when-pressing-enter-return-key?forum=officeitpro